# Lightning: Expression to get dynamic field on Object/SObject

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

In VF it is possible to do like:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!target[dynProperty]}"/>
```

Which expression can be used to do similar thing inside lightning component (not inside lightning js controller)? Doing like this

```
{!v.target[dynProperty]}
```

results in error:

> Failed to save undefined: expecting a positive integer, found 'dynProperty' at column 10 of expression: v.target[dynProperty]: Source

Are there any ideas how to do this inside component (not js controller)?

Answer (score 9):

The expression syntax does not support it.

You can use index array referencing, but not what you are doing here.

`{!v.target[3]}` - Okay

`{!v.target.prop}` - Okay

What you suggested, no joy.