# ui:inputNumber resetting the value to original and ignoring user typed value

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am seeing a weird behavior with `ui:inputNumber` and here is the sample code:

**Controller**:

```
public class ControllerClass {

    @AuraEnabled 
    public static List<A> getData() {
        List<A> aList = new List<A>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<3;i++){
            B bObj = new B(i);
            A aObj = new A(bObj);
            aList.add(aObj);
        }
        return aList;
    }

    public class A{
        @AuraEnabled
        public B bObj{get;set;}
        public A(B obj){
            bObj = obj;
        }
    }

    public class B{
        @AuraEnabled
        public Decimal someDecimal{get;set;}
        public B(Decimal d){
            someDecimal = d;
        }
    }
}
```

**ExampleApp.app**:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" controller="ControllerClass">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="dataMap" type="ControllerClass.A[]"/>

    <div style="width:100px;">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.dataMap}" var="dataVar">
            <ui:inputNumber aura:id="input-Number" class="slds-input" value="{! dataVar.bObj.someDecimal}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>

</aura:application>
```

**ExampleAppController.js:**

```
// Controller
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Request from server
        var action = component.get("c.getData");
        action.setCallback(this, function(result){
            component.set("v.dataMap", result.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Output**:

[image]

What is wrong with this code?

**Additional details/update:**

1. Looks like this is happening because the variable is two levels deep(`ControllerClass` -> `A` -> `B`). When I moved the decimal variable to class `A` and removed the class `B`(entirely) then it is working fine.
2. Same thing happening with `ui:inputText`. Looks like these tags don't like attribute two levels deep.
3. But I need data in this particular structure because `aura:iteration` tag does not allow dynamic index([related question1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137991/lightning-dynamic-index-in-aura-attribute-with-type-list), [related question2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70056/lightning-expression-to-get-dynamic-field-on-object-sobject?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a component just to handle you input, then it works like a charm.

Iteration:

```
 <div style="width:100px;">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.dataMap}" var="dataVar">
            <c:DecimalComponent dataObj="{!dataVar}"></c:DecimalComponent>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
```

Component definition:

```
<aura:component >
     <aura:attribute name="dataObj" type="ControllerClass.A"/>
     <ui:inputNumber aura:id="input-Number" class="slds-input" value="{!v.dataObj.bObj.someDecimal}"/>

</aura:component>
```

> Update: works in v40

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: Strange, it is working for me. See http://imgur.com/a/9wOHK

Comment: Thanks! I just updated all the involved metadata in this to v40 and it works. Accepting your answer. Thanks. You can update your answer that it is working in v40.

Answer (score 2):

How about storing your `B` object as a single element list on `A`?

I know that's less than optimal, but these are the sort of things you need to do to work with the `aura:iteration`

```
public class A{
    @AuraEnabled
    public B[] bObjs{get;set;}
    public A(B obj){
        bObj = obj;
    }
}
```

Then nest two iterators:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.dataMap}" var="dataVar">
  <span>
    <aura:iteration items="{!dataVar.bObjs}" var="bObj">
      <ui:inputNumber class="slds-input" value="{! bObj.someDecimal}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
  </span>
</aura:iteration>
```

The spans are there to prevent the iterators becoming confused - they may no longer be needed, but it used be necessary sometimes.

Comment: My usecase is that I need to display rows of data in two columns(like table with two columns but many rows). So my plan was to iterate over array of class A, and each instance of class A will have two instances of class B(representing column 1 & column 2). Not sure if I explained clear but can you suggest a workaround for this?